# Does dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id duplicate values?

Tags: oracle, transactions

I wrote oracle DML triggers to audit changes on multiple tables and save the changes in log tables, A trigger for each DML operation. I want to save dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id to group differnt DML operations that happened together.

May this function return duplicated values if database is restarted or something unexpected happened?

If yes, is there a better solution to group DML operations that happened in the same transaction with an id.

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_transa.htm#ARPLS062
LOCAL_TRANSACTION_ID Function
Returns the *local* (to instance) **unique** identifier for the current transaction

So in case of single instance database oracle guarantees it will be unique, but doesn't in case of RAC(cluster) or distributed XA transactions.

Comment: I think this answer suggests saving the instance id and system timestamp with transaction id https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:30725030554956 can i know the events or cases that may change the instance id.

Comment: @Mohammadwardeh in rare cases, for example in case of failover in rac one node, or if you are using normal RAC and your session may connect to any node (each node has own instance_id)

Comment: instead of system timestamp, i'd prefer start SCN :)